# React is not rendering both modules to the DOM

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to render two modules to the DOM.

When I do an 'npm start', it runs, but it's only showing the CharacterApp part. The main app(App) doesn't show up.

Here is my index.js file code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import CharacterApp from "./Characters/App";
import './CharacterApp/index.css';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
ReactDOM.render(<CharacterApp />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

CharacterApp is structured like this:

```
function App() {
 ....
}

export default App
```

And App looks like this:

```
const App = () => (
  ....
);

export default App;
```

Since it's not showing errors, I'm kinda lost as to why it's not showing both on the DOM.

Is there anything I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: you're rendering both to the same elementId: `document.getElementById("root")`. try creating a second element with a different id to render `CharacterApp` to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React will replace the entire content of the specified element with the render output when it is called - which is also why you should not render into `document.body`.

You will want to use two separate containers (perhaps create another div element and give it a unique id). Alternatively, if you don't need to have the separation of two react apps, you could instead combine the two into a single app:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.Fragment>
    <App />
    <CharacterApp />
  </React.Fragment>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    `ReactDOM.render(
      <React.Fragment>
       <App />
       <CharacterApp />
     </React.Fragment>, document.getElementById('root'))` 

> this will work. you can not use same 'root' for rendering 2
> components. instead you can group them in one or use different div
> Ids.
```

Answer (score 1):

How can it render two modules ? you are rendering the `App` module in a div with `id='root'` and then you are overwriting it with another module. Its the correct behaviour you can not render two modules like that.
If you want to render both modules in the same page, create a separate component and import your `App` and `CharacterApp` in that module and then render that new component in the dom i.e

```
ReactDOM.render( <YourNewComponent />  ,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

And if you do not want to create a seperate component, you can just simple do this.

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.Fragment>
    <App />
    <CharacterApp />
  </React.Fragment>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This code is the culprit:

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
ReactDOM.render(<CharacterApp />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

You're using the same `div` for showing your apps, so the second statement is replacing the `App` component with `CharacterApp`.

You can create two `div`s in `index.html`, say, `div#root-app` and `div#root-character-app`, and then render the two components to the two containers respectively.